# Convex Lens forming plane wavefront

Tags: optics, waves, geometric-optics, lenses

[image]

As we can see in the above diagram, as we move along the symmetric axis of the convex lens, **D** varies.
Therefore the rays coming out of the point source hitting different points of the lens surface must've travelled different 'optical path length' as they emerge out of the other surface, so how are they in phase?

Comment: Why would they be?

Comment: In diffraction theory, it happens to be the case.  At least in the book from where I learned diffraction, this way of obtaining the plane wave front was given before the theory.

Answer (score 0):

The rays have all traversed the same *optical* path lenght even though they have travelled different geometric distances.Remeber optical path length  is the geometric distance multiplied by the refractive index. Thus the waves that are passing  through the thick part of the lens have an optical path length in the lens that is longer than the geometric thickness of the lens.

Comment: I thought about that possibility too but it sounded too much unlikely that the adjustment would settle everything so well that we get plane wave out of it. Are there any articles or proofs related to this you know about, so that I could get reassured?

Comment: You adjust the position of the source until it is at the focus. Then, if the lens is of a good quality, you are guaranteed to get a plane wave. That's show wave optics works!